# How to change the foreground and background picture using code?

Tags: android, seekbar

I define the foreground picture and background picture in seekbar. Now it can display the foreground and background well in seekbar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- background picture -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/background"
          android:drawable="@drawable/back" />    
    <!-- energy diagram -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress" 
          android:drawable="@drawable/fill" />
</layer-list>
```

How could I realize change the foreground picture and background picture use Java code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***XML-LAYOUT-WISE***

**seekbar_progress.xml, place it inside your /res/drawable/ folder:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <nine-patch
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/seekbar_background"
        android:dither="true"
     />
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#80028ac8"
                android:centerColor="#80127fb1"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#a004638f"
                android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@android:id/progress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress_bg"
/>
</layer-list>
```

***SeekBar***

```
 <SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/frequency_slider"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="20"
    android:progress="0"
    android:secondaryProgress="0"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
    android:thumb="@drawable/seek_thumb"
 />
```

---

***Programmatically***

```
// ------------ custom seekbar
LayerDrawable layer = (LayerDrawable) verticalSeekBar_1.getProgressDrawable();

Drawable draw1 = (Drawable)layer.findDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.progress);
Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.scroll_on);

draw1 = new ClipDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap1), Gravity.AXIS_PULL_BEFORE, ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);

layer.setDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.progress, draw1);

Drawable draw2 = (Drawable) layer.findDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.background);

Bitmap bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.scroll_off);

draw2 = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap2);
layer.setDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.background, draw2);
```

Comment: Also refer these link for proper understanding http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/02/create-a-custom-styled-ui-slider-seekbar-in-android/

Answer (score 1):

`layer-list` xml resource actually creates a `LayerDrawable` instance. You can change its layers using `setDrawableByLayerId` method or create a new drawable instance with any layers you want.